# Dell PowerEdge C1100 Memory Configuration

Tags: memory, hardware

I have a Dell PowerEdge C1100 server with 48GB of DRAM (12x4GB modules, two modules per channel).

Now I'd like to add some memory. I do not want to buy more 4GB modules, because it will give me a total of 72GB DRAM maximum.
I'm trying to understand the doc which says:

> Memory modules of different sizes can be mixed in A1–A4 or B1–B4 
>   (for example, 2 GB and 4 GB), but all populated channels must have 
>   identical configurations. [PDF](http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_cloud_products/poweredge-c1100_Owner%27s%20Manual_en-us.pdf)

First of all, what is A1-A4, if slots have numbers A0-A2, B0-B2, ..., F0-F2?
And does it mean, the only way to expand the memory is to buy 6 8GB-modules for all empty slots to ensure all the channels have same size?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check Figure 3-9 for memory sockets & Table 3-1 for type of memory modules to install, you can install mixture of memory sizes but only thing you will need to be careful about is how you install them. you will need to install same sized memory in parallel channel. in your case, same memory size in socket A2 & D2, A1 & D1, similarly C0 & F0 and so on.